# Diagonalizing a matrix that is close to a circulant one in symmetry

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, permutation-cycles, circulant-matrices

Recently encountered a matrix that looks similar to a circulant, and in case of a $5\times 5$ matrix, we have:
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} \omega^0 c_0 & \omega^1 c_1 & \omega^2 c_2 & \omega^3 c_2 & \omega^4 c_1 \\ \omega^1 c_1 & \omega^2 c_0 & \omega^3 c_1 & \omega^4 c_2 & \omega^5 c_2 \\ \omega^2 c_2 & \omega^3 c_1 & \omega^4 c_0 & \omega^5 c_1 & \omega^6 c_2 \\ \omega^3 c_2 & \omega^4 c_2 & \omega^5 c_1 & \omega^6 c_0 & \omega^7 c_1 \\ \omega^4 c_1 & \omega^5 c_2 & \omega^6 c_2 & \omega^7 c_1 & \omega^8 c_0 \end{pmatrix},$$
where $\omega = e^{2 \pi /N}$ is the $N^{\text{th}}$ root of unity, where $N$ is the dimension on which the matrix operates, and $c_{l}$ are some complex valued constants. **So, this matrix closely resembles a complex symmetric circulant, except for these additional phase factors.**

Are there any ideas on how to diagonalize?
If no, at least may be there is a way to represent it as a product of 2-3 matrices, and that will give a hint on how to diagonalize it.

What I noticed up to now is that $P^{-2} \cdot \text{DFT}_{N}^{\dagger} \cdot A \cdot \text{DFT}_{N}$ produces a diagonal matrix, where $P$ is the circular shift matrix, and $\text{DFT}_{N}$ is the DFT matrix that diagonalizes any circulants. However, I must admit, that **the diagonal elements are not the eigenvalues of $A$**, which is understandable, as the transformation is not a similarity transformation, and this fact might be useless at all in the diagonalisation procedure :). However, it tells that a regular DFT matrix transforms $A$ to the following form:
$$ \text{DFT}_{N}^{\dagger} \cdot A \cdot \text{DFT}_{N} = \begin{pmatrix} 0^{(2 \times N-2)} & D^{(2 \times 2)} \\ D^{(N-2 \times N-2)} & 0^{(N-2 \times 2)} \end{pmatrix}, $$ where $0^{(j \times k)}$ is a matrix of zeros of the corresponding size, and $D^{(j \times k)}$ is some diagonal matrix. So, it is already pretty close to diagonal.

Comment: "this matrix closely resembles a complex symmetric circulant, except for these phase factors." : not really. In the case $\omega=1$, the matrix is not circulant. I can't see any reason why these matrices should be always diagonalizable.

Comment: Dear @TheSilverDoe, Pardon! My bad, I am editing the post

Comment: If you write $$ D = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0&0&0 \\0& \omega & 0 & 0 &0 \\0& 0 & \omega^2 & 0 &0 \\0& 0 & 0 & \omega^3 &0 \\0& 0 & 0 & 0 & \omega^4 \end{pmatrix}$$ and $$ C = \begin{pmatrix}  c_0 & c_1 &c_2 & c_2 &  c_1 \\  c_1 & c_0 & c_1 &  c_2 &  c_2 \\ c_2 & c_1 & c_0 &  c_1 &  c_2 \\  c_2 &  c_2 & c_1 &  c_0 &  c_1 \\  c_1 & c_2 &  c_2 &  c_1 & c_0 \end{pmatrix}$$then you have $$A = DCD$$
Note sure if it helps though...

Comment: Ye, if only the matrix was such that $D=D^{-1}$, then it would be the solution :). I wonder, where it is possible to permute non-square blocks in the matrix that I mention in the end of the post (mb with commutation matrices), but also looks like something possible to find the eigenvalues using Schur complement.

Comment: What I also found is that dependent on the parity of $N$, $\left(\text{DFT}_N^\dagger \cdot A \cdot \text{DFT}_N \right)^m$ is diagonal, where $m$ is either $N$ or $N/2$. Now it puzzles me, because it means that certain power of $A$ is diagonalized by DFT matrix, and the $A$ itself is not...

Comment: I think I will reduce the question to diagonalization to that transformed block matrix as the original question seems to be puzzling :)